# Retaining fields when converting .shp to GPX

Tags: qgis, gpx

I am currently planning a marine science expedition and need to convert some points from a .shp to a GPX for display in OpenCPN (chartplotting software) while retaining an extra field or two. I *swear* I got this to work a few years ago when I tried. I even wrote down some documentation to go back to (which does not appear to work anymore).

Currently, I have a set of points in a shapefile, it has "Name" (Text), "Sample" (Text), Lat (double), Long(double).

I had typically used QGIS to export the shapefile (save as) GPX. I have made sure that GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS = YES, which I could have sworn was what allowed the additional fields to export along with the name.

Unfortunately no matter what I do, when I import the GPX into OpenCPN I only get the "Name," but no "Sample" field.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you add the gpx back into QGIS does it have the extra field?  Does some other software, such as the free DNR Garmin/DNR GPS, see the extra field in the gpx?  Can they save the shapefile as a gpx that OpenCPN shows both fields?

Comment: Added it back into QGIS and it has "ogr_Biosample, ogr_Lat, ogr_Long" all retained at the end of the attribute table.

So I think you are correct that it must be a software issue on the OpenCPN side of things.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me. I made a test with GDAL 3.7.0dev and this GeoJSON file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name":"foo", "sample":"bar", "lat":1.23456, "lon":7.890123 }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1.23456,7.890123]} }
]
}
```

and with this command

```
ogr2ogr -f gpx -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES gpxtest.gpx gpxtest.json
```

and the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="GDAL 3.7.0dev-5ce7ba068f" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogr="http://osgeo.org/gdal" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<metadata><bounds minlat="7.890123000000000" minlon="1.234560000000000" maxlat="7.890123000000000" maxlon="1.234560000000000"/></metadata>                      
<wpt lat="7.890123" lon="1.23456">
  <name>foo</name>
  <extensions>
    <ogr:sample>bar</ogr:sample>
    <ogr:lat>1.23456</ogr:lat>
    <ogr:lon>7.890123</ogr:lon>
  </extensions>
</wpt>
</gpx>
```

Now ogrinfo shows this:

```
ogrinfo gpxtest3.gpx waypoints

INFO: Open of `gpxtest3.gpx'
      using driver `GPX' successful.

Layer name: waypoints
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (1.234560, 7.890123) - (1.234560, 7.890123)
Layer SRS WKT:
....
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
ele: Real (0.0)
time: DateTime (0.0)
magvar: Real (0.0)
geoidheight: Real (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
cmt: String (0.0)
desc: String (0.0)
src: String (0.0)
link1_href: String (0.0)
link1_text: String (0.0)
link1_type: String (0.0)
link2_href: String (0.0)
link2_text: String (0.0)
link2_type: String (0.0)
sym: String (0.0)
type: String (0.0)
fix: String (0.0)
sat: Integer (0.0)
hdop: Real (0.0)
vdop: Real (0.0)
pdop: Real (0.0)
ageofdgpsdata: Real (0.0)
dgpsid: Integer (0.0)
ogr_sample: String (0.0)
ogr_lat: Real (0.0)
ogr_lon: Real (0.0)
OGRFeature(waypoints):0
  name (String) = foo
  ogr_sample (String) = bar
  ogr_lat (Real) = 1.23456
  ogr_lon (Real) = 7.890123
  POINT (1.23456 7.890123)
```